# Android Room Kotlin inner join

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I have two entities
Accounts:

```
@Entity(tableName = "accounts",foreignKeys = arrayOf(
        ForeignKey(
                entity = Currency::class,
                parentColumns = arrayOf("id"),
                childColumns = arrayOf("currencyId"),
                onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        )
))
data class Account (
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
        var id:Int=0,
        @ColumnInfo(name="name")
        var accountName:String,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "balance")
        var initialBalance:Double,
        var currencyId:Int,
        var date:Date,
        var isDefault:Boolean=true
){
    constructor():this(0,"",0.0,0,Date(),false)
}
```

And Currencies:

```
@Entity(tableName = "currencies")
data class Currency(
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
        var id:Int=0,
        @ColumnInfo(name="name")
        var currencyName:String,
        @ColumnInfo(name="code")
        var currencyCode:String
)
{
    constructor():this(0,"","")

    override fun toString(): String =currencyCode
}
```

I want to embed a `currency` object in `account`. As you can see, I have one-to-many relationship between `currencies` and `accounts`. When I query the `accounts` entity I want to view its currency too.
I tried adding an `@Embedded` field in `account` entity but it doesn't work **obviously there is something I'm misunderstanding** , the field is returned with null "No exception just null". And if possible to "flatten" the `currency` object inside the `account` object, this would be much better.

The point of all of this is, I want to display all accounts in `RecyclerView` with their currencies information. I'm now confused between `@Embedded` and `@Relation` any help would be much appreciated.
**Edit**
I don't know if this might help:
This is my `AccountDao`:

```
@Dao
interface AccountDao {
    @Insert
    fun insertAll(items:Array<Account>)

    @Update
    fun update(item:Account)

    @Delete
    fun delete(item:Account)

    @Query("select * from accounts")
    fun getAll():LiveData<Array<Account>>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get it to work. The solution was to create a separate (POJO or POKO whatever) class, I called it `AccountModel`:

```
class AccountModel{
    var accountId:Int = 0
    var accountName:String = ""
    var accountInitialBalance:Double = 0.0
    var accountCreationDate: Date = Date()
    var currencyId:Int = 0
    var currencyCode:String = ""
    var isDefaultAccount:Boolean = false
    constructor()
    constructor(id:Int,name:String,balance:Double,date:Date,currencyId:Int,currencyCode:String,isDefault:Boolean){
        this.accountId = id
        this.accountName = name
        this.accountInitialBalance = balance
        this.accountCreationDate = date
        this.currencyId = currencyId
        this.currencyCode = currencyCode
        this.isDefaultAccount= isDefault
    }
    fun toAccount():Account = Account(this.accountId,this.accountName,this.accountInitialBalance,this.currencyId,this.accountCreationDate,this.isDefaultAccount)
}
```

And then, constructing the query to do a normal `inner join` as if you are doing `inner join` for ordinary SQL database. Like this:

```
@Query("select accounts.id as accountId," +
            "accounts.name as accountName," +
            "accounts.balance as accountInitialBalance," +
            "accounts.currencyId," +
            "accounts.date as accountCreationDate," +
            "accounts.isDefault as isDefaultAccount," +
            "currencies.code as currencyCode " +
            "from accounts inner join currencies on accounts.currencyId=currencies.id")
    fun getAll():LiveData<Array<AccountModel>>
```

Apparently, you can use `as x` to project this column to a `x` field in the returned object, as you can tell, in the database the column is `accounts.id` but in my `AccountModel` it is a `accountId`.
And the really impressive thing by Google Room is that I was able to get a `LiveData` of `AccountModel` even though I'm adding an `Account` object which is really clever.

Answer (score 4):

I won't recommend the above method because you end up writing the same properties (repeating yourself) aka boilerplate code.

Use the [@Embedded](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Embedded.html) and [Relation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Relation.html) annotation in the following way and your code will most probably look like this:

```
data class AccountWithCurrency (
    @Embedded
    var account: Account? = null,
    @Relation(parentColumn = "id", entityColumn = "currencyId")
    var currency: List<Currency>? = null,
){
constructor() : this(Account(), emptyList())
}
```

Comment: Thanks for contribution, but I've mentioned that "And if possible to "flatten" the currency object inside the account object, this would be much better." that's for my case is better. Anyways, +1 for tell me how to use `@Relation` and `@Embedded` the right way.

Comment: This won't work if you filter records after joining tables